# Update de um registro com base em outra tabela

Tags: mysql

Tenho duas tabelas iguais, que contem os seguintes campos `id`, `nome`, `idade`.

Sendo elas `tabelasse` tabelaB`.

O que quero fazer é atualizar um registro da `tabelaB` com base na `tabelaA`, consigo fazer isso assim:

```
UPDATE tabelaB 
SET nome =(SELECT nome FROM tabelaA WHERE id = '1')
WHERE
id ='1'
```

O problema é que quero atualizar todos os dados da tabelas e não quero fazer algo assim:

```
UPDATE tabelaB 
SET nome =(SELECT nome FROM tabelaA WHERE id = '1'), idade =(SELECT idade FROM tabelaA WHERE id = '1')
WHERE
id ='1'
```

Lembrando que os registros mantem o mesmos `id` em ambas as tabelas.

Answer (score -1):

Acho que você pode fazer um Update com Join. Ex:

```
UPDATE tabelaB b
inner join tabelaA a on a.id = b.id
SET b.nome = a.nome, b.idade = a.idade
WHERE b.id = '1'
```

Espero que ajude